# GCS - Create bucket from App Engine - 403:Forbidden error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create a GCS bucket using the JAVA Api from an App Engine project.

I get the following error with not much further information.

403 FORBIDDEN
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}

Based on reading up on internet, I have already checked the following

**Enable Billing - Done.. 
Enable GoogleCloudStorage API - Done ..**

Inspite of doing these, I see the error.

This is how I am creating the storage object ---

---

```
httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(); 

credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();

//Add Scopes
List<String> colls = new ArrayList<String>();

colls.addAll(StorageScopes.all());

if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
credential = credential.createScoped(colls);
}


//Build storage
storage = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("projectName").build();


Bucket newBucket = storage.buckets().insert("projectName", new Bucket()
                  .setName(bktName).setLocation("US")).execute();
```

---

The same code used to work in a different project.
However, I am unable to create buckets with a 403 error on a new project that I have created..

Hope to hear something from you guys soon !!!

Thanks,

Srikanth

Comment: Also tried with AppIdentityCredential.. Still no luck  AppIdentityCredential credential = new AppIdentityCredential(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write"));

Comment: Have you tried typing projectName in the cloud console manually to see if it's available? Remember bucket names are globally unique.

Comment: Yes, I have tried creating buckets by typing those bucket names in the admin console and it works just fine. However, when I use the JSON API I get this error that hardly contains any further information.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the Google Cloud Storage JSON API (via the google developers console) for that project?

As a side note, you may want to consider using [gcloud-java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java) for storage which should be a better experience on Java.

Comment: Hi Ozarov I have already enabled the JSON Api for cloud storage. What I don't understand is that I have the same piece of code running fine under another project ID. So I am suspecting it is just a configuration issue on the console. I do see some changes on the console UI in the last few weeks. Wondering if I need to enable something else in the console that I am not able to see :(

Comment: Enabling the API is per project, but I assume you already know that. You should compare the two projects and look for differences. Also, how do you get the projectName? Again, I suggest you to try gcloud-java which, aside from being a nicer to use API, takes away the boilerplate code associated with authentication and project settings.

Comment: Sure, I will check that out. Is that an offering by google themselves ? Or is that a 3rd party open source API ? Coz I would want to stick with what google offers to be able to upgrade in this fast changing and evolving cloud API world.

Comment: This is a Google open source project (part of [GoogleCloudPlatform](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/)).